# Parsing Tag for text

Tags: html, excel, vba, tags

I have a VBA script that I've been using to extract company reporting dates off the London Stock Exchange website. They have changed their web query interface. I've been trying to modify the script.

I've taken an extract from the scripts, below the URL requests data for a particular month in 2019, however there is no data for the requested field. The webpage response is "Sorry, we couldn't find any results for your criteria. Please try again.". I wish to find and check for the existence of this text, and exit the loop if true.

My script first parses HTML tags named "section", then within each section I attempt to parse each HTML tag named "div". The text is within one of the "div" tags.

I can breakpoint the code within the "sction" loop, however it does not pick up any "div" tags, even though I'm pretty sure the "div" tags are within the "section" tags.

I'm also not sure if my string comparison works, as I haven't been able to check this due to the inner loop not executing.

```
Dim oDom As Object: Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
Dim tbl As Object
Dim sction As Object
Dim spn As Object
Dim div_txt As Object

Dim TestSplit() As String
Dim innerText As String
Dim htmlEle1 As Object

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp.6.0")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news?tab=news-explorer&indices=NMX&headlinetypes=1&headlines=42&period=custom&beforedate=20190731&afterdate=20190701"
    .send
    oDom.body.innerHtml = .responseText
End With
    
'check to see if the page is empty
For Each sction In oDom.body.getElementsByTagName("section")
    innerText = sction.innerText
    For Each htmlEle1 In sction.getElementsByTagName("div")
        innerText = htmlEle1
        If [innerText = "Sorry, we couldn't find any results for your criteria. Please try again."] Then Exit For
    Next htmlEle1
Next sction
```

Comment: Your example URL gives "Sorry, we couldn't find any results for your criteria. Please try again."  It would be useful to provide a working URL if you need help parsing the results.

Comment: Sorry I tend to jump straight to the code so sometimes miss the details

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Const NO_HITS As String = "Sorry, we couldn't find any results for your criteria. Please try again."

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp.6.0")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news?tab=news-explorer&indices=NMX&headlinetypes=1&headlines=42&period=custom&beforedate=20190731&afterdate=20190701"
    .send
    If InStr(.responseText, NO_HITS ) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No results"
    Else
        Debug.Print "OK"
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much for your help.

Is it generally easier to search globally than to try to search through the tags as I was doing?

Comment: That just seemed like the most straightforward way to do it...  Generally you wouldn't take that approach when web scraping though, since the data you're looking for is typically less unique than a string like that.